# send confirmation to delete from within php

Tags: javascript, php, html

When I press the button in the html section, I want to get approval before deleting the form, are you sure you want to delete it, like no or yes, but can you explain by explaining the logic that I need to do this with php? When I did it with js, I got confirmation, but without saying yes, I saw that it was processed in my database record.

Comment: You need to do it in JS, and if they say no, you have to prevent the form submission.

Comment: To do it in PHP you would have to put the approval into the form.